# Riemann integration and the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, functions

[image: q]

Hello, I am unsure of how to define the partition to find a suitable result for the Riemann integrable, how do I do this for a discontinuous function?

Comment: Piecewise continuous implies Riemann integrable.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I do not study piecewise continuity in my course

Comment: What did you learn about integrability of functions? Maybe you're supposed to use the definition, what's your definition of Riemann integral?

Comment: Theorem: If g is Riemann integrable on [a,b] and if f(x)=g(x) except for a finite number of points in [a,b] the f is Riemann inferable and int_[a,b] f = int_[a,b] g.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut A function f:[a,b]->R is Riemann integrable over [a,b] if J=j. J:=infU(f,P) and j:=supL(f,p).

Comment: Is it true to say that this function does not have a primitive as f is not continuous on [-1,1]?

Comment: Then if p is any partition of your interval, your upper and lower sums will differ only one the subdivision containing 0. Since $f$ is bounded, with refinment of partitions with longest length $\rightarrow 0$, you will find that $U-L \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: $s(x)$ does not have a primitive on the whole interval $[-1,1]$, since the integral is not differentiable at 0 (the integral is |x|...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You  may omit *finitely* many points from the integration without changing the integral. This allows you to compute $$
  \int_{-1}^1 s(x)\,dx = \int_{-1}^0 -1 \,dx + \int_0^1 1 \,dx = -1 + 1 = 0
$$
without worrying about how often this includes the point $0$, and about whether $s$ is continuous there or not.